# One wifi hotspot client uses all the bandwidth, causing problems for others. Is this configurable in a smarter way?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I use my Pixel 2 as a wifi hotspot daily. I usually works great even with 2-3 connected clients, but I had a problem recently where two computers were connected, one playing a game and the other watching a streamed video.

The game started getting disconnects and network problems and it became clear that the other client, streaming video, must have been consuming the maximum bandwidth available, leaving almost nothing to the gaming client. Once the video stream was stopped, the gaming client worked fine again.

This surprised me but I don't know how these things work in detail. I would hope for a setting that could create some fairness, for example "allow max 80/20 bandwidth consumption between two clients" or 50/50 for simplicity. I know that video streaming has different ways to adapt to the available bandwidth so I'm sure the video client would be fine with less, but the game needs some minimum to work.

Comment: Use [tc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc.8.html) on Android device.

Answer (score 0):

On the computer which is streaming videos, check (toggle) the Pixel2 hotspot as a metered connection which would help a bit